# Pandoc not recognising metadata block

Tags: html, pandoc

I have a template `templates/default.html` that looks like this: (some lines omitted for brevity)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Title here - $title$</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>...</div>
        <div id="content">
            <header>
                ...
            </header>

            <main role="main">
                <h1>$title$</h1>
                $body$
            </main>

            <footer>
                ...
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I then have a file `pages/index.html` that looks like this:

```
---
title: Home
---
<p>My Website</p>

<h2>Heading</h2>
```

When I run it through pandoc with the command

```
pandoc -t html pages/index.html --template=templates/default.html -o output.html
```

I get the warning:

```
[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty <title> element.
  Please specify either 'title' or 'pagetitle' in the metadata.
  Falling back to 'index'
```

And the result is

```
            <main role="main">
                <h1></h1>
                <p>--- title: Home ---</p>
                <p>My Website</p>
                <h2>Heading</h2>
            </main>
```

Why does pandoc fail to recognise the YAML metadata block in this instance?

I have tried this on pandoc 2.0.6 and 2.9.2.1 with the same result.